# Change Require Validator of the Firstname and Lastname on Checkout uiComponent

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I created a custom address select attribute where if changed, the validator of first name and last name will turn to not required. Is there a way to apply this logic on the checkout uiComponent shipping address form? I tried doing this using jQuery but is not working and seems to be not the correct way.

Comment: You want to change validation or a remove validation for firstname and lastname ?

Comment: @CharmiPatel yes, sir.